# Filter a list of dictionary in python

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

If I have a list of dictionary objects in a list similar to below , is there a way for me to filter the objects that I need using certain attributes (eg: floor = 1 , use = retail etc) or should I iterate over all the object to find what I need?

```
{'Floor':'1', 'Use':'Retail', 'Square Footage':'6598', 'Price':'6500', 'RoomID':'100', 'Capacity':'55'}
{'Floor':'1', 'Use':'Retail', 'Square Footage':'1900', 'Price':'3000', 'RoomID':'101', 'Capacity':'25'}
{'Floor':'1', 'Use':'Retail', 'Square Footage':'1850', 'Price':'3000', 'RoomID':'102', 'Capacity':'25'}
{'Floor':'1', 'Use':'Restroom', 'Square Footage':'250', 'Price':'0', 'RoomID':'103', 'Capacity':'0'}
{'Floor':'1', 'Use':'Maintenance', 'Square Footage':'150', 'Price':'0', 'RoomID':'104', 'Capacity':'0'}
{'Floor':'2', 'Use':'Studio', 'Square Footage':'875', 'Price':'850', 'RoomID':'200', 'Capacity':'2'}
{'Floor':'2', 'Use':'Studio', 'Square Footage':'734', 'Price':'850', 'RoomID':'201', 'Capacity':'2'}
{'Floor':'2', 'Use':'Studio', 'Square Footage':'624', 'Price':'850', 'RoomID':'202', 'Capacity':'2'}
{'Floor':'2', 'Use':'Studio', 'Square Footage':'624', 'Price':'850', 'RoomID':'203', 'Capacity':'2'}
{'Floor':'2', 'Use':'Double', 'Square Footage':'850', 'Price':'1245', 'RoomID':'204', 'Capacity':'4'}
{'Floor':'2', 'Use':'Double', 'Square Footage':'850', 'Price':'1245', 'RoomID':'205', 'Capacity':'4'}
{'Floor':'2', 'Use':'Double', 'Square Footage':'850', 'Price':'1245', 'RoomID':'206', 'Capacity':'4'}
{'Floor':'2', 'Use':'Double', 'Square Footage':'850', 'Price':'1245', 'RoomID':'207', 'Capacity':'4'}
{'Floor':'2', 'Use':'Common', 'Square Footage':'731', 'Price':'0', 'RoomID':'208', 'Capacity':'0'}
{'Floor':'2', 'Use':'Quad', 'Square Footage':'1100', 'Price':'1650', 'RoomID':'209', 'Capacity':'8'}
{'Floor':'2', 'Use':'Quad', 'Square Footage':'1005', 'Price':'1650', 'RoomID':'210', 'Capacity':'8'}
{'Floor':'2', 'Use':'Quad', 'Square Footage':'1205', 'Price':'1650', 'RoomID':'211', 'Capacity':'8'}
```

Comment: Also: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter

Comment: I believe this question has been wrongly marked as a dupe. It's about filtering a list of dicts, not filtering keys from the dict itself...

Comment: Thanks @Rishav, that's my understanding too after looking at the answer referenced.

Comment: Anyway: you can use a list comprehension to achieve what you want for example - `[d for d in my_list if d["floor"] == "2" or d["Use"] == "Retail"]` etc

Comment: Thanks , will try this

Comment: You can also use a build-in function filter:
`filtered_list = list(filter(lambda d: d['Floor'] == '1', list_of_dicts))`